# decrypt encrypted gpg file using external secret key

Tags: encryption, gnupg

I encryptd a file using `gpg`, now I want to decrypt the file.

Is there any way to decrypt the file without need to import the secret file?

We have the secret key in a file called `key.sec`; can we pass the secret file to `gpg` as a parameter (when we run the `decrypt` command from the `bash` command line) to use when decrypting the encrypted file? Or must we import the secret key then decrypt the encrypted files?

Comment: Related: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/104941/is-there-a-way-to-embed-a-gpg-public-key-in-a-script-without-adding-it-to-the-ke and http://lists.gnupg.org/pipermail/gnupg-users/2004-October/023409.html

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You must add the secret key to a keyring. From the `gpg(1)` documentation:

```
   --no-default-keyring
          Do not add the default keyrings to the list of
          keyrings. Note that GnuPG will not operate without any
          keyrings, so if you use this option and do not provide
          alternate keyrings via --keyring or --secret-keyring,
          then GnuPG will still use the default public or secret
          keyrings.
```

You could `--import --no-default-keyring --secret-keyring temporary` to import the key, use `--secret-keyring temporary` when decrypting the content, then delete the `~/.gnupg/temporary.gpg` file when you're done. But that's just a work-around.

Comment: Wouldn't a key.sec make a keyring with a single key all by itself? Or am I confusing protocols?

Comment: @owl: I've never looked deeply enough into GPG to figure out if a single lone key "is" a keyring, but I'd be surprised; the sentence _Note that GnuPG will not operate without any keyrings_ feels like an ambiguous statement that lone keys are _not_ keyrings.

Comment: Please note that `--secret-keyring` is obsolete and a no-op in GnuPG 2.1. There is no _secret keyring_ - private keys are stored in a directory `private-keys-v1.d` which is owned and operated by the `gpg-agent`.

Comment: @starfry, if you know gnupg2 well enough, please consider adding a new answer here. (And please comment back, so I can return and upvote :)

Comment: @sarnold I've added an answer with more details.

Answer (score 9):

**You have to import the secret key to use it** but the way that secret keys are managed by GnuPG version 2.x has changed. There is a `gpg-agent` daemon that handles secret keys access and its use is mandatory from version 2.1.

Here is a way that you can quickly create a temporary keyring to decrypt with a secret key that is contained in a file:

```
$ mkdir -m 700 ~/.gnupg-temp
$ gpg --homedir .gnupg-temp --import key.sec
$ gpg --homedir .gnupg-temp -d an_ecrypted_file
```

If you want to clean up afterwards, stop the agent and remove the directory:

```
$ gpg-connect-agent --homedir .gnupg-temp KILLAGENT /bye
$ rm -r ~/.gnupg-temp
```

*There used to be an option `--secret-keyring` about which the [documentation](https://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gnupg/GPG-Configuration-Options.html#GPG-Configuration-Options) for version 2.1 has this to say:*

> This is an obsolete option and ignored. All secret keys are stored in the private-keys-v1.d directory below the GnuPG home directory.

*The `private-keys-v1.d` directory (wthin the `--homedir` or `~/.gnupg`) is owned and operated by the agent.*

Answer (score 2):

The objective of the OP Mohammed appears to be keeping his **PUBLIC** and **SECRET** key apart. After all, ***do we want to keep the Secret key with the data it was used to encrypt?*** Thus, Mohammed's and 10,650+ others (at the time I write this) are interested in if/how it's possible. ***Indeed it is, and this is how you do it:***

The publicly-facing host only has two keys: ***Both are Public Keys***

1. Your ***GPG*** Public key used to encrypt data
2. Your ***SSH*** Public key in ***.ssh/authorized_keys*** to facilitate non-interactive logins.

***Round-tripping an encrypted file using Public-Secret key separation:***
The following bash snippet when executed on the host with the ***Secret Key*** will fetch the crypted file from the DMZ host via scp, and squirt the gpg decrypted standard output back onto the DMZ host into a file so it can be read/operated upon. This code is tested and known to work correctly:

```
echo "$(gpg -d $(scp myuser@192.168.1.10:/home/myuser/test-gpg.txt.asc .;ls ./test-gpg.txt.asc))" | ssh myuser@192.168.1.10 'cat > /home/myuser/test-gpg.txt'
```

***Note that you will still be prompted for a password once decryption begins***. But once the password is supplied, the script continues and injects the decrypted gpg stream into a file on DMZ host.

And don't forget to do an `rm test-gpg.txt` of the decrypted file once the operation that required it's contents to be readable has been completed.

So yes, ***very*** possible to keep your secret key apart from the publicly accessible host where encryption occurs and your secret key tucked safely away in a host outside of that DMZ.  HTH- Terrence Houlahan